# How to remove comments in yaml when dump to string using ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-2.7, yaml

Recently I was trying to load old.yaml and dump to new.yaml using ruamel.yaml.

I need to remove comment lines in old.yaml when dump to new.yaml. Suppose I have the following file:

old.yaml:

```
xyz:
  a: 1    # comment 1
  b: 2

test1:
  # before test2
  test2:
    # after test2
    test3: 3
```

and new.yaml:

```
xyz:
  a: 1
  b: 2

test1:
  test2:
    test3: 3
```